# Should I embed wordpress with iFrame?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I want to embed an existing blog into my website  (e.g. www.site.com/blog/index.php into www.site.com/blog.php ) but I'm wondering if simply using an iFrame is sustainable - I read somewhere it's being phased out..?

Comment: how about pulling all the blog contents in from the RSS feed and then parsing them and displaying them how you want?

Comment: hmmm.... I kind of like that it's a full blown blog.. I really just want my nav.php to show on the side too

Comment: just to make sure i understand. The blog and the site are on different domains right? Otherwise a simple redirect would suffice...

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try to put this in your www.site.com/blog.php

```
<iframe src="www.site.com/blog/index.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks.. that's what I was thinking (seems much easier than styling the blog to match the site or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be modify the blog's header and navigation to match your website's navigation. iFrames kill SEO and your blog will have a hard time getting into Google results.

Comment: that's the kind of thing I was wondering about. 
Is there a simple way of calling e.g. the nav.php my main site uses in the blog header? The problem is that the blog sits in a subdirectory...

Comment: Sure you can. You'll have to use PHP includes. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp and you might have to do some CSS changes to make it perfect.